# Is it worth it to make a custom method of bulk SQL processing for C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm about to undergo a fairly large project and if it goes at all how I hope there will be a lot of database calls going on constantly. I'm wondering if it would be worth it to, instead of using the entity framework, create a custom method of doing all SQL operations in large batches. What factors would make it more or less desirable/efficient to use bulk processing vs. normal use of the entity framework? I'd appreciate any resources regarding this. I can see a number of issues like trying to read a value before it gets updated or while it is being updated, of course there are ways around this but I'm wondering if there is a resource that outlines all the pros and cons so I don't have to write out a model of how I would do it in order to consider all the possible trade offs.

Edit: Ok I realize I didn't give much detail. The project is a messaging service. When messages come in they will already be encrypted json strings. Those json strings will be written to the database for retrieval. Let me know if you need more information than this.

Comment: "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Comment: Are you processing data in bulk or are you thinking of staging a set of changes and commiting them all at once?

Comment: I don't think I'll be doing any bulk processing of the data. It will just be creation/retrieval of accounts and messages.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to do bulk operations via an ORM is often a bad idea (although it depends on what you call "bulk"; 50 records - fine; 50,000 records - trouble). It *can work*, and indeed *under the hood* EF has support for bulk operations that  go down to the DB, but the *primary* EF interface tends to be object-based, which means you need to fetch the data (and any required child data), mutate it locally, and then have a transaction that spans pushing all that data back to the server, possibly involving race conditions (timestamp / rowversion violations), etc.

Note that  TSQL *already supports* this without *any* of those problems. It is called: TSQL! `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc. The plus side is that you're no longer writing object-oriented compiler-checked code. The down side is that you're no longer writing object-oriented compiler-checked code :)

Comment: So probably just best to update when the server receives the request?

Comment: @Hephaestious not enough context to comment; what server, what request, and why does it need to update at all?

Comment: It's a messenging service so for example A sends M to B. A's client sends it to the server and the server adds M to a list of B's messages in the db. Then B's client does a request for pending messages, the server checks the database, sends B's client M and deletes M from the database.

Answer (score 0):

EF is slower than ADO.NET but the clear trade off is simpler programming and reduced chance of error. Your options

1) Use stored procedure with EF. If you go this route, I like using database projects so that stored procedures and all database components are treated as first class citizens when it comes to source code control (see MSDN's [MSDN's Working with Database Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx)).

2) Use ADO.NET and SQLCommand obviously with raw SQL or stored procedures. My issue here there is a lot more programmer work. I mean a lot and developers cost a lot of money compared to "getting a faster server".

3) Another alternative is to define table types in SQL Server and use Table-Value Parameters in ADO.NET (see [MSDN's Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)). This lets you pass data in bulk. You can use both data readers and DataTable's. Remember a data reader is vastly faster than a DataTable (binary format versus XML representation).

Just remember you are incurring extra development, QA, project management costs if you deviate from EF which offers faster development time and reduced chance of error since you're not hard coding tables/columns/stored procedure names in C#. EF automatically syncs so any changes to the database show up as compile time errors in an EF application. They are the dreaded run-time error when using ADO.NET.

[Edit] Just read your edit above. If you have a high volume of messages and they are one record type (meaning written the same way to the same few table/tables) then you optimize with ADO.NET by using EF in 98% of the code and dropping to ADO.NET/Stored Procedures or EF/Stored Procedures for the high volume JSON messages. A small bit of manually coding at a lower level could likely be worth the speed tradeoff.

Comment: "simpler programming and reduced chance of error" - well, *different* programming and *different* errors; neither is trivial, and frankly it is easy to make huge errors with any ORM or none; "My issue here there is a lot more programmer work" - tools like "dapper" can make that work essentially zero

Comment: Use caution when walking down the dark path that leads down to realm of third party tools. The life time of code often out lives the time of third party tools. On a project there was debate once to use ReiserFS versus ext3 (this is an example or relying on third party not a solution to the question). Look up Hans Reiser -- we picked ext3 but ReiserFS would not have been the best third party choice with regards to long term support. :-) Point well taken though.

Comment: well, for me it isn't a 3rd party tool :)